# What does this CSS .row > div > div { ... } mean?

Tags: css

This is a basic question, but I cant find answer anywhere. So do you guys know what does `>` do within CSS?

```
.row > div > div {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: it means the first div on the childs..

Comment: For example, <div class="row"><div class="one"><div class="one"></div></div></div> it means, .row > .one > .one

Comment: Comments above are misleading. `>` does not refer to the first div/child. It refers to the **direct descendant**.

Comment: It means div in div in a tag with "row" class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is immediate child selector.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_combinator

Answer (score 0):

It's mean (children of). So in your code, that line means: **Get the div element that has a parent div, and the parent div has a parent element that has a class named "row"**.

Comment: direct child of